# Big picture on how to create objects in iOS apps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

Until now I've coded my iOS applications using "pre-made" UI objects such as UItableViews, UIButtons and UIcollectionviews and it's been great.

But then I open instagram or other famous applications and I cannot recognise the UIobjects used in those applications as the ones I'm used to.

I make some examples: the shutter of instagram camera is something I've not seen before in pre-made objects, the "swipeable" snapchat user's cells have different behaviours in respect to the ones of a common UITableViewCell.

So my question in this case is : do developers use already made "UIObjects" and then they customise them, or they use different Libraries that allow you to create better objects?

I'm a novice in this field so probably this question doesn't have so much sense for a skilled developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big companies make millions of dollars off of their single application and have dozens of iOS developers working on it. As a result, they can afford to expend resources in making their own custom UI elements.

If an element is popular enough, sometimes an individual developer or small group will duplicate the behavior of an element and distribute it for free to the rest of us. One source of custom UI elements is cocoapods.org